Loading .wasm file compiled from Rust gives "CompileError: wasm validation error: at offset 184: function body too big"
I was trying to create my web assembly module using Rust`s wasm-pack and use it within the .html file. I tried to use replit.com to generate the .wasm .
I created a new blank repl, installed rustup and wasm-pack, added wasm32-unknown-unknown target, ran cargo init, created src/lib.rs and put this code in there:
use wasm_bindgen::prelude::*;

#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn sum_3(p1: u8, p2: u8, p3: u8) -> u8 {
    p1 + p2 + p3
}

Here is how my Cargo.toml file looked like:
[package]
name = "test"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib"]

[dependencies]
target = "2.1.0"
wasm-bindgen = "0.2.92"

Then I ran these two commands:
rustup default stable
wasm-pack build --target web

The wasm file was generated, I downloaded it and tried to use it on my own PC (the actions described below were done on my own computer). The wasm file was put into the new folder where this html was located too:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Wasm</title>
</head>
<body>

    <script>
        function process(e) {
            
        }

        WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(fetch("./my.wasm", {mode: 'no-cors'}), {}).then(result => {
            process(result.instance.exports);
        })
    </script>

</body>
</html>

The html was served with the running of this python file:
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles

app = FastAPI()

app.mount("/", StaticFiles(directory="myf"))

with this command: fastapi dev server.py.
After opening html in the browser in the console I saw: Uncaught (in promise) CompileError: wasm validation error: at offset 184: function body too big.
The .wasm file weights like 13kb.
Here is the link to my repl: https://replit.com/@benjaminaugustb/testnew. You can fork it and test everything yourself.
Here is the link to a zip with the folder I served: https://github.com/user-attachments/files/16354465/myf.zip.
Am I doing something wrong? Does web assembly js api have any limits related to size?

If you compile the wasm on your own computer, does it work?

@ChayimFriedman I didnt try to compile it on my own PC yet

@ChayimFriedman So I tried to compile it on my own PC and it worked. Then I went to replit, removed the target = "2.1.0" from my Cargo.toml and it worked too. And the thing is that if I try to add the target dependency now, it wont compile (gives Compiling target v2.1.0 error[E0308]: mismatched types    --> /home/runner/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/target-2.1.0/src/lib.rs:141:16) . I dont actually know what's happening
